# Excel LEN, SEARCH and FIND Double Space Bug?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am attempting to add conditional formatting to an Excel 2010 worksheet and having trouble with one of the formulas involved.  From what I'm able to determine Excel is counting a double space as 1 character, and double spaces are what I'm trying to identify!

This is my worksheet, with notations for the purpose of illustration:

[image: Snip of Excel worksheet showing formulas in use]

It is hard to see, but the string in cell `B45` has a double-space between "1XXX" and "TRUCK".  `B46` is the exact same string, but with only a single space in the same position.  The formulas for cells `M45:N46` are annotated with the result showing.

The issue is why the two formula results are equal when the `SUBSTITUTE` should replace the double space with a single space?  I've tried using `SEARCH` and `FIND` for "  " (double space) with similar results.

I started out using a comparison between the two values for my conditional formatting to determine whether a cell contained a double space, but with this issue I have been unable to complete this simple task!  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look to me that there are 41 characters in `B45`. I counted 40 twice, 33 characters and 7 spaces (unless I am not understanding your question). Perhaps you have a trailing space?

Comment: The length is 40 in B45 with the double space. If `SUBSTITUTE` does not substitute it, then they are not default space. Maybe they are non-breaking-spaces? Try `SUBSTITUTE(B45,CHAR(160)&CHAR(160)," ") ` or any combinations of `" "&CHAR(160)`...

Comment: @Brian:  You are correct about the character count, and I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @Axel:  A good suggestion, alas every combination I have tried has not changed the resulting character count.  I experimented some with `CHAR` yesterday when I first encountered this issue, too.  I have also tried `LEN(TRIM(B45))` to no avail.

Comment: fwiw, I am unable to replicate this. `=LEN(SUBSTITUTE([cell reference],"[double space]","[single space]"))` works as expected for me (Excel 2010, v 14.0.7166.5000)

Comment: try `LEN(TRIM(CLEAN(B45)))`

Comment: In E45 put `=MID($B$45,ROW(1:1),1)` then in F45 put `=CODE(E45)` and copy both formula down till you get errors. in the E column.  Then look at the code for the spaces and see what it is.

Comment: @Scott: `E45` = 2 and `F45` = 49

Comment: @spacetanker You need to get the _problem character_ out from the string in `B45`. `=CODE()` returns the value for the first character. I believe that's what Scott is asking for. That will tell if it is a space or not.

Comment: You need to copy them down, as you do it will iterate through the entire string.  find the spaces in question then look at those codes.

Comment: @Scott:  When I reread your comment I picked up on copying it down.  In the result there weren't errors, but I did find the codes were 32 followed by 160 for the "double space".  Using this I was able to alter the `SUBSTITUTE` formula and obtain the desired 39 character result.  Thank you!  Now I can only hope it's always 32 followed by 160 for the "double space", but that's another problem.

Comment: @Scott:  How do I mark this solved, since the solution stems from your comment?

Comment: don't worry about it, glad we could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change your formula a bit by substitute double space "  " with ZERO space "" instead of ONE space " " as per your current formula. Then N45 will return 38 if there is ONE double space (as the double space gets replaced with nothing), and 36 if there are TWO double space and so on.

Hope this helps. 
Cheers,

Comment: Curiously, on my worksheet your suggestion does not alter the result.  It still shows 40 characters!  Here is the formula I used:  `LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B43, "  ", ""))`; see any typos?

Comment: Can you try LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B45, "  ", "")) ? Really weird as it works on my worksheet. Also maybe you can try to TRIM the text before applying the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Using double space worked for me so I'm not really sure. But give this a try:

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(1)," "))
```

Comment: Same result is rendered.